# The method getSubmittedFileName is undefined for the type Part

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Here's the code snippet of .java file...I've imported javax.servlet.http.part to use getsubmittedFileName method, but it's not working.
Even i have servlet version 4.0..
tomcat version 9.0.82..
How can i fix the problem?

```
package com.admin.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;


@WebServlet("/add_books")
@MultipartConfig
public class BooksAdd  extends HttpServlet{

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        try {
            
            String bookName=req.getParameter("bname");
            String author=req.getParameter("author");
            Double price=Double.parseDouble(req.getParameter("price"));
            String categories=req.getParameter("btype");
            String status=req.getParameter("bstatus");
            Part part=req.getPart("bimg");
            String fileName=part.getSubmittedFileName();
            
        
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    
    

}
```

note:- it's a maven project.......
here are the dependencies which are in the project....

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>

        

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.22</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Comment: When i am trying to run the program it shows me an error on localhost server:-  java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method getSubmittedFileName() is undefined for the type Part.

Comment: well i am using servlet version :- 4.0 ....tomcat apache server:- 9.0.82  ......i am trying to build dynamic web project and want to fetch userinput data into server, for that i am using javax.servlet ..i tried jakarta.servlet as well, but it throwing me error of /path not found. so i went back to javax.servlet.

Comment: hi, i've added dependencies in my question, plz help me